# Trying to create eventDrops SAMPLE but not Succeeded

Tags: d3.js

Iam using d3 version 4.12.2
and eventDrops.js downloaded from this below link
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/thoka/ca508531e9a016fb815477621f9d6aae/raw/32b3a1e79208a840666882fec60804c68a96bf7f/eventdrops.js
and my code is

```
<html>
<head><title>asdasd</title>
    <script src="./d3.js"></script>
    <script src="./eventDrops.js"></script>
    <script lang="javascript">
        function test() {
            var hardData = [{
name: 'sensor1',
dates: [
    new Date(1458068401000),
    new Date(1458068401000),
    new Date(1458068403000),
    new Date(1458068404000),
    new Date(1458068405000),
    new Date(1458068406000),
    new Date(1458068411000),
    new Date(1458068413000),
    new Date(1458068415000),
    new Date(1458068416000),
],}]; var eventDropsChart = d3.chart.eventDrops(); d3.select('body')
.datum(hardData)
.call(eventDropsChart);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="test()"></body></html>
```

2). which version of d3 works with eventDrops?

Thanks & Regards,

Govardhan

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which version is the one you mentionned. I would recommend using the official one, available on: https://unpkg.com/event-drops. Be careful: this is the last version with [breaking changes](https://github.com/marmelab/EventDrops/blob/master/MIGRATION-1.0.md) compared to previous versions.

D3 version 4 works with the 1.0.0 version.

For a working example of how it works, you can take a look on the [demo code](https://github.com/marmelab/EventDrops/blob/master/demo/demo.js) and adapt it according to your needs. :)